# android Fragment in ViewPager can't update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i create 3 Fragment use ViewPager, this is ViewPagerAdapter :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FragFile tab1 = new FragFile();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            FragAll tab2 = new FragAll();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            FragFav tab3 = new FragFav();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

this is Activity1 hold 3 Fragment :

```
public class Acc1 extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager view_pager;

TabLayout tab_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acc1);

    tab_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("File"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("All"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Fav"));

    view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tab_layout.getTabCount());

    view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

    tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

}
```

}

In MainActivity, go to Activity1 hold 3 Fragment.
In Activity1, Fragment2(FragAll) and Fragment3(FragFav) can go to Acctivity2.
In Activity2 can edit data, this data will show on Fragment3(FragFav).

My problem is :
When edit data on Activity2, and come back Activity1 use backpress, data in Fragment3(FragFav) not change.(i think app hold Fragment state).
but when leave Acitivity1 use backpress to MainActivity, and go to Activity1 again, data on Fragment3(FragFav) was change.(same thing if when come back Activity1 from Activity2, choose Fragment1(FragFile) and choose Fragment3(FragFav), data will change)
i know i need to refresh or reset Fragment3(FragFav) when from Activity2 comeback to Activity1, but i don't know how to to that.
Can anybody help me?

this is update I follow Drv:
I create AppConstants class in java folder:

```
public class AppConstants {
public static boolean refreshPage=false;
public int fragment_position=0;
```

}

In Activity1, I change code to :

```
public class Acc1 extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager view_pager;

TabLayout tab_layout;

AppConstants ac;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acc1);

    tab_layout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("File"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("All"));
    tab_layout.addTab(tab_layout.newTab().setText("Fav"));

    view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tab_layout.getTabCount());

    view_pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tab_layout));

    tab_layout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            view_pager.setCurrentItem(ac.fragment_position);
            ac.fragment_position=tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (AppConstants.refreshPage) {
        AppConstants.refreshPage = false;
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
}
```

in Activity2, I add this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(Acc2.this, Acc1.class);
    AppConstants.refreshPage=true;
    startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

but when chose Fragment2(FragAll) and Fragment3(FragFile), I get error in "view_pager.setCurrentItem(ac.fragment_position);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use some global flag as below:

```
public class AppConstants{

 public static boolean refreshPage=false;
 public static int fragment_position=0;

}
```

In backpress of your Activity2, write as below:

```
AppConstants.refreshPage=true;
```

In onResume of your Activity1, write as below:

```
if (AppConstants.refreshPage) {
        AppConstants.refreshPage = false;
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

And in your Activity1, save your selected tab position as below:

```
YOURTABLAYOUT.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            AppConstants.fragment_position=tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

And in its onCreate write as below:

```
 YOURVIEWPAGER.setCurrentItem(AppConstants.fragment_position);
```

Comment: I follow you, but when comeback from Activity1 use backpress on Activity2, it don't show old Fragment, it show Fragment1(FragFile)

Comment: @1234abcd Check my answer and you will get what you want.

Comment: what is fragment_position?

Comment: Position of your selected fragment or tab declared globally in AppConstants.

Comment: When you are selecting any of your tabs, you are saving position of your selected tab in setOnTabSelectedListener method globally, and when you are coming first time or refreshing your activity1, you are using this globally selected tab position to automatically load the fragment you last clicked when leaving activity1.

Comment: I follow you but get error(maybe I don't understand your code so much). I was update my code in my question. can you fix it?

Comment: Where are you getting error?Please post your complete codes if possible so that I can help you.

Comment: I' m sorry I forgot to write static in AppConstants. Now wherever you have used ac.fragment_position, replace it with AppConstants.fragment_position.

Comment: my update code is same thing you show me? I need to define AppConstants ac in Acivity1 and use it or use direct AppConstants? sorry because i'm new in java

Comment: Remove AppConstants ac; line from Ac1 and just use AppConstants.

Comment: @1234abcd If my answer helped you atleast do upvote for it.

Comment: :) Happiieee Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

You can Update your Data by Calling Method of Fragment.

First Create One Method in your Fragment Like,

```
public void onUpdateData(Boolean isUpdated) {
    if (isUpdated) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //update your data

    }
}
```

Then Register Your Fragment in Activity and pass context(this)

```
FragFav mFragFav = new FragFav(this);
```

just don't forget to create constructor in your fragment to avoid Null object Exception.

```
public FragFav(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Now call this Method from activity wherever data is updated and method will trigger in Fragment..

```
mFragFav.onUpdateData(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet:
Notify FragmentStatePagerAdapter at onPageSelected.

```
 if (mSectionsPagerAdapter != null) {
                            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
```

Main code:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity(),getChildFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    Log.e("changed","mViewPager "+position);
                    try {
                        if (mSectionsPagerAdapter != null) {
                            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
```

SectionsPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        Context mContext;
        FragmentManager fm1;
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fm1=fm;
//            if(multiple_actions.isExpanded()){
//                multiple_actions.collapse();
//            }
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()==0){
                return ActivityListing.newInstance(0,"preview");
            }else if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()==1){
                return ActivityListing.newInstance(1,"current");
            }else if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()==2){
                return ActivityListing.newInstance(2,"next");
            }else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.preview);
                case 1:
                    return getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.current);
                case 2:
                    return getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.next);
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            if(fm1.getFragments().contains(object))
                return POSITION_NONE;
            else
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
        }

    }
```